# Add an event into iCal in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

There is a requirement in my application in which, when I take an appointment of a doctor for a particular day, that day should be added in iCal. and it should generate an alert view on that particular day.

So, I am not getting how to add an event in iCal. Please give me some answer for this.

The scenario is, I do have a string (NSString) of "date" and "notes" for that particular appointment. Then, how to insert all this information into iCal.

Code:

```
- (NSArray *)fetchEventsForToday {

    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

    // endDate is 1 day = 60*60*24 seconds = 86400 seconds from startDate
    NSDate *endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:86400];

    // Create the predicate. Pass it the default calendar.
    NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:defaultCalendar];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate 
                                                                    calendars:calendarArray]; 

    // Fetch all events that match the predicate.
    NSArray *events = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

    return events;
}


// Overriding EKEventEditViewDelegate method to update event store according to user actions.
- (void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller 
          didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action {

    NSError *error = nil;
    EKEvent *thisEvent = controller.event;

    switch (action) {
        case EKEventEditViewActionCanceled:
            // Edit action canceled, do nothing. 
            break;

        case EKEventEditViewActionSaved:
            // When user hit "Done" button, save the newly created event to the event store, 
            // and reload table view.
            // If the new event is being added to the default calendar, then update its 
            // eventsList.
            if (self.defaultCalendar ==  thisEvent.calendar) {
                [self.eventsList addObject:thisEvent];
            }
            [controller.eventStore saveEvent:controller.event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            break;

        case EKEventEditViewActionDeleted:
            // When deleting an event, remove the event from the event store, 
            // and reload table view.
            // If deleting an event from the currenly default calendar, then update its 
            // eventsList.
            if (self.defaultCalendar ==  thisEvent.calendar) {
                [self.eventsList removeObject:thisEvent];
            }
            [controller.eventStore removeEvent:thisEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    // Dismiss the modal view controller
    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

// Set the calendar edited by EKEventEditViewController to our chosen calendar - the default calendar.
- (EKCalendar *)eventEditViewControllerDefaultCalendarForNewEvents:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller 
{
    EKCalendar *calendarForEdit = self.defaultCalendar;
    return calendarForEdit;
}
```

I have used these functions and delegate methods. Please give me idea that, when the user gets alerted for the reminder, how to open up that information regarding that event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [EventKit framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765).  You can ask the [`EKEventStore`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009567) for its calendars, and then use those calendars to create a predicate that lets you [find events that match the criteria you're looking for](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009567).  Or you can create a new [`EKEvent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/EKEvent) object and [save it into the event store](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009567).

Comment: Hello Sir, I have done the same thing as you said... But, when the user gets alerted for that particular event, two options come with that, "Close" and "View Event". above that options, we can see the title, location, start time for that reminder. But, the notes section regarding that is not there. How do i access it? Also, the "View Event" option for that alert view is not showing anything..... Please help me out of this...

Answer (score 1):

Based on Apple Documentation, this has changed a bit as of iOS 6.0.

1) You should request access to the user's calendar via "requestAccessToEntityType:completion:" and execute the event handling inside of a block.

2) You need to commit your event now or pass the "commit" param to your save/remove call

Everything else stays the same...

Add the EventKit framework and #import  to your code.

To add an event:

```
   EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (!granted) { return; }
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
    event.title = @"Event Title";
    event.startDate = [NSDate date]; //today
    event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
    [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
    NSString *savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;  //this is so you can access this event later
}];
```

Remove the event:

```
    EKEventStore* store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (!granted) { return; }
    EKEvent* eventToRemove = [store eventWithIdentifier:savedEventId];
    if (eventToRemove) {
        NSError* error = nil;
        [store removeEvent:eventToRemove span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error];
    }
}];
```