# Extract information from built-in calendar in iphone through my app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, calendar, xcode4.3

I'm a new xcode developer, and I want to ask how to get event that have been written by a user in iphone calender into my app?
Is it possible?

THANK YOU!!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684759/add-an-event-into-ical-in-iphone-application) post will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look at [Event kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for fetching details from built-in calendar