# Display event on calendar objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

I have an app that make a calendar event on iOS, the event is added correctly, but I want to display the calendar app with the event as the user added the event;  and I have no idea to how i can call to the calendar app.

Comment: you cannot show the calendar app in your project but u can use other framework for showing calendar in your project with all the events present in your calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]];
```

When you call this action, It will open the calendar, sadly, i can only open the calendar in today or in 31/12/2000, but it works!.

Answer (score 0):

You may need the EventKit framework. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684759/add-an-event-into-ical-in-iphone-application), especially the answer pertaining to IOS 6 that isn't checked. That can help you get started.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already add the events to calendar, But i need to display the event in the calendar app. calling it from a button or something.